# How to fix the quantization axis of an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory, spectroscopy

Suppose I send linearly polarized light onto a hydrogen atom. Using first order perturbation theory one can show that, depending on the relative polarization of the light to the quantization axis of the hydrogen, either $$m=0 \quad\quad\textrm{or}\quad\quad  m=\pm1$$ for the transitions, that can be excited. $m=0$ holds true if the polarization is aligned with the direction of the quantization axis.

How is this quantization axis fixed? I would assume it's direction unknown until it gets hit by the EM wave and then collapses in a certain, random direction. But how can one fix the quantization axis beforehand, so that e.g. only $m=0$ transitions take place?

Comment: I don't know what the "quantization axis of an atom" is supposed to be. You determine $m$ relative to an axis, but that axis is not a property of the atom - you can literally pick any other axis and still describe the same system, you're just changing the basis of your space of states.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  Obviously you're right.. Now it makes much more sense. I got completely stuck and thought that the $m$-valaues are properties of the atom...

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I beg to differ. When the system is in an eigenstate of the $L_z$ operator, it can't be simultaneously in an eigenstate of either $L_x$ or $L_y$, as the eigenstate of $L_z$ can always be written as a linear superposition of $L_x$ and $L_y$. The same goes for spin, and total angular momentum operators.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, like for instance in an ion trap experiment, the quantization axis for the atoms is defined by applying a static B field in a known direction.  If no magnetic field is present the spin is in an equal superposition of each direction.

Answer (score -2):

Linearly polarised light consists of an equal amount of right and left circularly polarised photons. An equal amount on average, that is, subject to quantum fluctuation. This will cause, on average, an equal amount of $\delta m=+1$ and $\delta m=-1$ transitions, again subject to fluctuation. The quantisation axis is parallel to the photon propagation. These would be $1s \rightarrow 2p_{\pm}$ transitions, if hydrogen is in its ground state initially.